# How to get the secrets from Key vaults using power shell script?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have a requirement to get the secrets from key vault. This should be done in powershell script and this powershell script execute through azure devops pipeline (not inline script) and the file saved in azure repo.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'Contoso' -Name 'secret1'
```

Get the current version of a specific secret in this case 'secret1'. You can output it to a file using

`| Out-File -FilePath .\secrets.txt`

More information in the official Doc Page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/get-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-6.13.0